# How to split a Python module into multiple files?

Tags: python, python-module

I have a single Python module which contains 3 classes: A, A1 and A2.
A1 and A2 derive from A. A contains functions which operate on A1 and A2.

This all works fine when it's in one .py file. But that file has grown quite long and I would like to split A1 and A2 off into their own files. How can I split this file despite a circular dependency?

Comment: How about this, any help??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353990/how-to-split-python-code-into-modules-and-join-them-on-import

Answer (score 12, accepted):

modA.py:

```
class A(...):
   ...
```

modA1.py:

```
import modA
class A1(modA.A):
   ...
```

modA2.py:

```
import modA
class A2(modA.A):
   ...
```

modfull:

```
from modA import A
from modA1 import A1
from modA2 import A2
```

Even if A "processes" A1s and A2s you should be fine because thanks to duck typing you don't need to import the actual names.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I split this file with despite a circular dependency?

Option 1: break the cycles:  Put the base class in its own module, the derived classes in additional modules, and functions operating on those derived classes in yet another module.

---

Option 2: Ignore the cycles, import only modules/packages into the global namespace, IE:

#### foo.py

```
class Bar:
    "Frobs Quuxen"
```

Should never be imported as `from foo import Bar`, just use `import foo` and refer to `foo.Bar` in functions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the core of your question is that you don't want

```
a.py to imports a1
if
a1.py imports a.
```

However, that's totally fine in python. However, do make sure that you don't have any code outside of functions/classes in a system with multiple modules, because the order that that runs in will vary based on where you import it, what that imports, the phase of the moon, etc.