# How to split PYTHON code into modules and join them on import

Tags: python-3.x

I have a very long code of a while loop with if statements. It has about 2000 colms. 
It goes like this:

```
While True:
for x in code:
  if value == 100:
    print('done it')
  elif < 100:
    x + code
      if value == 100:
        print...
```

It goes almost like this..

How do I split into modules that would connects back when importing them. Am new to Python

Comment: Code that repetitive would benefit more from rearchitecting rather than splitting.

Comment: what is rearchitecting?

Comment: It's thinking about the problem in other ways in order to improve the code.

Comment: I was thinking of modules, is there another way other than modules

Comment: Modules is refactoring, not rearchitecting. Refactoring will be of limited use until you fix the underlying architecture.

Comment: wow, ok, thank you. Doe that mean I start afresh? being noew to python comes with much demand

Comment: Not necessarily afresh, but until you get some experience it's probably best. Describe the process that you want the code to perform in as succinct yet complete a form as possible, and then examine Python's facilities to see which match up with each piece of what you've described.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39175/discussion-between-wakamdr-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)