# Using java-like imports in a pythonic way

Tags: python

I'm looking for a pythonic way to deal with the following package structure problem.

In my project I implemented a couple of file parsers. This was my first idea of the packaging structure:

```
myproject
└── parsers
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── parser_a.py
    └── parser_b.py
```

The drawback of this approach is that the required imports are rather verbose:

```
from myproject.parser.parser_a import Parser_A
from myproject.parser.parser_b import Parser_B
```

I think this import would be nicer:

```
from myproject.parser import Parser_A
from myproject.parser import Parser_B
```

There are at least two ways to achieve this:

i) Putting all parsers in one huge python module.

```
myproject
└── parser.py
```

But this would result in a huge, probably confusing *parser.py* file

ii) Splitting the *parser.py* module over multiple files[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799286/how-to-split-a-python-module-into-multiple-files)]

```
myproject
├── parser.py
└── parsers
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── parser_a.py
    └── parser_b.py
```

Content of *parser.py*:

```
from parsers.parser_a import ParserA
from parsers.parser_b import ParserB
```

This approach avoids the one-file problem, but imo it looks a little hacky.

It's probably a matter of opinion but I'm looking for a pythonic way to deal with that kind of problem. Is it acceptable to use those shortened, java-like imports? And if so - what is the preferred way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would put everything in parser.py

Another common option is to have this layout:

```
myproject
└── parsers
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── parser_a.py
    └── parser_b.py
```

and have the following content in `__init__.py`:

```
from parsers.parser_a import ParserA
from parsers.parser_b import ParserB
```

There isn't really one specific rule for this, so it is up to you what to use.

Remember that python isn't java. It is totally fine to define multiple classes in one file.